# How to make windows from an application start with "Always on Visible Workspace"

Tags: 15.04, pidgin

The main use case is pidgin windows. I make use of all 4 workspaces and I want any pidgin window that pops up to be visible in any of the workspaces I'm currently working in, and stay visible regardless of if I switch to some other workspace.

There are a few suggestions and answers already to this, but none work for me. Using `Ubuntu 15.04`. I've gone though them below.

---

I've tried `devilspie` with the following script:

```
(if (is (application_name) "Pidgin")
    (begin (pin))
)
```

No luck.

---

I've tried installing compiz settings manager,

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins
```

Then setting `Window Rules` to `Sticky` for `class=Pidgin`

No luck with that either.

Nothing seems to make it that window "Always on Visible Workspace"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Window Rules` method will work, but seems to require a restart to take effect; or at least for Pidgin conversation windows that appears to be the case.

> I've tried installing compiz settings manager,
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
> sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins
> ```
>
> Then setting `Window Rules` to `Sticky` for `class=Pidgin`

Comment: Please, could you accept your own answer, as that what works for you. & i believe it does.